# Is there any way to start or start fragment from service class

Tags: java, android, service, fragment

**Here is my code in which getSupportFragmentManger() is not working inside the Service class**

```
 Fragment fragment = new OfferNotificationFragment();
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag("tag6");
    if (fragment == null) {  // not added
        fragment = new OfferNotificationFragment();//add fragment
        ft.replace(R.id.coordinate_layout, fragment, "tag6");
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    } else {  // already added
        ft.remove(fragment);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE);
    }
    ft.commit();
```

Comment: Fragments cannot exist by themselves. They have to be attached to an activity context. You can start an activity from the service and put this code snippet inside that activity.